# Calling Platform.runLater for multiple tasks in javaFX application

Tags: multithreading, javafx, javafx-2

I have a JavaFX application which has several methods attached to it and there is one method like everything that calls all methods
like

```
DFF
Lookup
Profile
Everything
```

`Everything` calls all these methods I am trying to implement threading on `Everything` methods to call these methods and then after the `List`s are popuplated I transfer the control to another fxml to display it in table view using tab pane.

```
public void runEverything(){
    List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList();

    Task task = new Task() {
        protected Object call() throws Exception {                
            dataAOL = aol.getAolReport(InstanceController.validateto, InstanceController.validatefrom, pattern.getText());
            System.out.println("Method"+AOLScreenController.dataAOL.size());             

            return null;
        } 

    };
    Task task1 = new Task() {
        protected Object call() throws Exception {                
            dataProfile = aol.getAolReport(InstanceController.validateto, InstanceController.validatefrom, pattern.getText());
            System.out.println("Method"+AOLScreenController.dataAOL.size());                

            return null;
        } 

    };

    tasks.add(task);
    tasks.add(task1);

    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    for (Task t : tasks) {               
        threadPool.submit(t);
    }
    threadPool.shutdown();
}
```

I need to call the `Platform.runLater` method only once after all threads have finished execution so that I load the fxml view and in the means while a progress bar will loop in the new fxml and ui will not lag .
but I do not know where to place my `Platform.runLater` code

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
     @Override public void run() {
         try {
             Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("AolRun.fxml"));
             SmartCC.fxmlval.add("AOLScreen.fxml");
             SmartCC.stageval.add((Stage) run.getScene().getWindow());
             Stage stage = new Stage();
             stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
             stage = (Stage) run.getScene().getWindow();
             Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
             stage.setScene(scene);
             scene.getStylesheets().add("/css/Style.css");
             stage.setTitle("AOL Output ");
             stage.setResizable(false);
             stage.show();
         } catch (IOException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(AOLScreenController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
     }
 });
```

If I place it inside the last task there is thread synchronization errors and I do not know about that.
I am very new to threads and javafx threads please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just add a `onSucceded` handler to the tasks. This handler is run on the application thread after successful completion of the tasks:

```
public void runEverything() {
    ...

    EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent> handler = new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
         private int remainingTasks = tasks.size();

         @Override
         public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
              if ((--remainingTasks) == 0) {
                  try {
                      Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("AolRun.fxml"));
                      SmartCC.fxmlval.add("AOLScreen.fxml");
                      SmartCC.stageval.add((Stage) run.getScne().getWindow());
                      Stage stage = new Stage();
                      stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
                      stage = (Stage) run.getScene().getWindow();
                      Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
                      stage.setScene(scene);
                      scene.getStylesheets().add("/css/Style.css");
                      stage.setTitle("AOL Output ");
                      stage.setResizable(false);
                      stage.show();
                  } catch (IOException ex) {
                      Logger.getLogger(AOLScreenController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                  }
              }
         }

    };

    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    for (Task t : tasks) {
        t.setOnSuceeded(handler);
        threadPool.submit(t);
    }
    threadPool.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: Sorry to be asking this fabian but what do we need to add on that success handler method in each of these tasks and also why are we not using platform.runlater method here

Comment: @RahulSingh `Task` makes sure the `onSuceeded` handler code runs on the JavaFX application thread, which is what you're also achieving by using `Platform.runLater`. Furthermore you need to add this to every task to know when the last one is finished (AFAIK this is when you want to call the code for stage creation).

Comment: Thanks it works but one issue here is that 9 out of 10 times it works but sometimes it is stuck there any thread synchronization issues over here as when i print it is stuck at a task and dosn't move forward.

Comment: @RahulSingh If a task is stuck, this has nothing to do with the code I added. But with the code you use inside those `Task`s. I recommend reading some tutorials about multithreading in java in that case, since writing a tutorial on multithreading is beyond the scope of an answer and you didn't post any information in the question allowing to identify the issue. Furthermore if an exception is thrown in the `Task.call` methods, `onSucceeded` isn't called...

Comment: I am already learning from tutorials cave of programming on multithreading, and those methods in these tasks are nothing but a method that fetches data from database and puts it in a report nothing else. some times it is fine sometimes its hangs or dosn't give report i  thing its related to deadlock or synchronization

Comment: I have one small doubt, does this pattern which i have written follow multi threading architecture of java fx ?